# Problem with perl signal INT

Tags: perl

I have the following perl code on windows activestate perl 5.8

```
  $SIG{INT}=\&clean;

  ...
  sub clean {

  print 'cleaning...';
  ...
  ...
  exit 0;

  }
```

but when i try to close my program by Ctrl^c it didn't enter the sub clean at all could someone help why did i miss something ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Windows doesn't provide signals as in Unix.

From `man perlwin32`:

> Signal handling may not behave as on Unix platforms (where it doesn't
>       exactly "behave", either :).  For instance, calling "die()" or "exit()"
>       from signal handlers will cause an exception, since most implementations
>       of "signal()" on Win32 are severely crippled.  Thus, signals may
>       work only for simple things like setting a flag variable in the handler.
>       Using signals under this port should currently be considered
>       unsupported.

Comment: Hm… that quotation became ugly. How do I remove the colours?

Comment: Signal handling is crippled in Windows, but `SIGINT` is one of the few signals that Windows (and Windows-flavored Perl) can emulate pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say no.  I can't see anything wrong with what you're doing.  I wrote a test program that actually runs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$SIG{INT}=\&clean;

sub clean {
    print 'caught';
}
sleep 10;
```

Tested on Linux, this works as expected, but I don't have AS perl handy to try it.  Try it yourself on your machine.

Also, print to STDERR to ensure it's not something very odd going on with print buffering.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the script given by @ijw (modified to be what it is below) does not work under Active State Perl version v5.10.1:

```
This is perl, v5.10.1 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
(with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

My modification below adds the autoflush calls (as otherwise the sleep
below would not show the print statement output at all while
sleeping):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use IO;
use strict;
use warnings;

# Set autoflushing on to stdout and stderr.  Otherwise, system() call and stdout output does not show up in proper sequence,
# especially on Windows:
STDOUT->autoflush(1);
STDERR->autoflush(1);

$SIG{INT}=\&clean;

sub clean {
    print "caught\n";
    exit (0);
}

print "before sleep\n";
sleep 100;
print "after sleep and then exiting\n";
exit (0);
```

When I commented out the following lines in that script above:

```
$SIG{INT}=\&clean;

sub clean {
    print "caught\n";
    exit (0);
}
```

And then hitting CTRL-C during the sleep, the script does terminate and show this message:

```
Terminating on signal SIGINT(2)
```

Hence it must actually still be true (well, for ActiveState Perl v5.10.1) what `man perlwin32` states:

> ... most implementations of "signal()" on Win32 are severely crippled. ...

For future reference:

1. [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=334827) refers to the use of [Win32::API](http://search.cpan.org/~acalpini/Win32-API-0.41/) to setup a call to the `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` Win32 function.
2. All about [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://www.google.com/search?q=SetConsoleCtrlHandler+inurl%3amsdn).