# Perl 5.10.0 Signal Handler Issue

Tags: perl

Interrupting the program below with Ctrl + C causes a "Segmentation fault" with perl 5.10.0. It works correctly with perl 5.8.8. Any idea why?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# just changing the shebang line to use perl 5.10.0 causes it to seg fault
# when interrupted with Ctrl + C

use strict;
use warnings;

$SIG{INT}=\&clean;

sub clean {
    print 'caught';
}
sleep 10;
```

(program taken from [Problem with perl signal INT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761443/problem-with-perl-signal-int))

The perl 5.10 version is:

```
$ perl5.10.0 -v

This is perl, v5.10.0 built for i686-linux-thread-multi
(with 3 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2007, Larry Wall

Binary build 1002 [283697] provided by ActiveState http://www.ActiveState.com
Built Jan 10 2008 07:35:18
...
```

The linux distribution:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.18-128.7.1.el5 (mockbuild@hs20-bc2-3.build.redhat.com)
(gcc version  4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)) #1 SMP Wed Aug 19 04:00:49 EDT 2009
```

Thanks

Comment: I would highly recommend that you post this problem on http://www.perlmonks.org/ instead of here.  There are a lot more Perl people there who can test it on a lot more platforms, and who may know about bugs like this.  If it is still a bug in current Perl platforms, it should be definitely reported with the `perlbug` utility.

Comment: Why 5.10.0? Have you tried 5.10.1 or even 5.12.3?

Comment: nope. that's the latest we have access to in our systems. I could build my own but I would do that almost as a last resort.

Comment: It's not that hard to build a new Perl, or to download a new binary from ActiveState.

Comment: A *lot* of bugs were fixed in 5.10.1. I'd start by checking if it's already been fixed.

Comment: Could you run it under gdb, best with debug perl package installed, and after segfault post result of gdb 'bt' command here?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to provide some more details, such as what operating system/version you are using, whether you're using system perl, perlbrew, active perl, etc.  Trying this against Perl 5.12.3 built from Perlbrew on Snow Leopard, I cannot reproduce the issue.

I would also follow the suggestion of asking on perlmonks.org, too.

Comment: any particular linux distribution? i can try and spin up a vm and throw active perl on there and see what happens

Comment: just tried it on Perl 5.12.3 -as expected it worked without issues. There must be some bug in Perl 5.10.0 related to this. Thank you all.